# How is this expression for a GHZ state obtained in the nature paper by Pan et al. (2000)?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, quantum-optics

Can someone tell me how the authors of the paper "Experimental test of quantum nonlocality" (Nature link to [abstract](https://www.nature.com/articles/35000514)) have rewritten their equation 1 in terms of equation 2 and 3?

[image]

Comment: https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~quopt/ghz.pdf

Comment: To clarify: are you asking how $(4)$ comes from $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$? If so, then you can probably just substitute inverted $(2)$ and inverted $(3)$ into $(1)$... If not, then could you clarify what the question is?

Comment: Yes, that was my question. How can I substitute into 1 when equations 2 and 3 are V' and H' ???

Comment: Do you mean expressing H and V in terms of H' and V' from 2 and 3 and then inserting them into 1??

Answer (score 4):

First, in order to express $|H'\rangle$, $|V'\rangle$, $|R\rangle$ and $|L\rangle$ in terms of $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$, add and subtract the pair of equations $(2)$ and add and subtract the pair $(3)$, to get

$$
|H'\rangle + |V'\rangle = \sqrt2|H\rangle \\
|H'\rangle - |V'\rangle = \sqrt2|V\rangle \\
|R\rangle + |L\rangle = \sqrt2|H\rangle \\
|R\rangle - |L\rangle = i\sqrt2|V\rangle
$$

which means that

$$
|H\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|H'\rangle + |V'\rangle\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|R\rangle + |L\rangle\right) \\
|V\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|H'\rangle - |V'\rangle\right) = \frac{1}{i\sqrt{2}}\left(|R\rangle - |L\rangle\right).
$$

Substituting the last equations into $(1)$ according to the choices of polarization in text, we obtain

$$
\begin{align}
|\Psi\rangle &= \frac{|H\rangle|H\rangle|H\rangle + |V\rangle|V\rangle|V\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \\
& = \frac{(|R\rangle + |L\rangle)(|R\rangle + |L\rangle)(|H'\rangle + |V'\rangle)-(|R\rangle - |L\rangle)(|R\rangle - |L\rangle)(|H'\rangle - |V'\rangle)}{4}.
\end{align}
$$

Notice that the only terms that do not cancel are those with odd number of kets in $\{|L\rangle,|V'\rangle\}$, i.e.

$$
|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left(|L\rangle|R\rangle|H'\rangle + |R\rangle|L\rangle|H'\rangle + |R\rangle|R\rangle|V'\rangle + |L\rangle|L\rangle|V'\rangle\right)
$$

in agreement with $(4)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Hi @HaxhiPantina and welcome to QCSE! If an answer solved your doubts, consider accepting it by clicking the check mark. This helps keep focus on questions that haven’t been solved.